# Loop through multiple form and get their input values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically generating forms using jquery. How can I loop through all the forms and alert their input values.

**CODE FOR GENERATING FORMS**

```js
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'api/PayrollSystem/GetEmployeeSalaryAmount?AdminId=' + 1,
  success: function(data) {

    if (Object.keys(data).length == 0) {
      $.alert({
        title: 'Saved',
        content: 'Account Number Saved!',
      });
      var row = ('<tr ><td colspan="3" text-align="center"> <b>No Registered Users</b></td></tr>');
      $('.EmpTable').append(row);
    } else {
      $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        var rows = ('<div id="form_div"><form method="post"><table  class="table table-hover employee_table' + index + ' " align=center><thead><tr><td><b>Employee</td> <td><b>Amount</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><b>' + value.FullName + '</b></td><td><input type="hidden" class="form-control Leavename" name="Leavename[]" value="Basic" placeholder="Enter Leave Name">  <input readonly class="form-control LeaveAmount" type="number" name="LeaveAmount[]" value=' + value.SalaryAmount + ' /><input  class="form-control EmpId" type="hidden" name="Id[]" value=' + value.Id + ' /></td></tr><tr id="row' + index + 1 + '"><td><input type="text" class="form-control Leavename" name="Leavename[]" placeholder="Enter Leave Name">  </td><td>   <input type="number" class="form-control LeaveAmount" name="LeaveAmount[]" placeholder="Enter Leave Amount"></td>  </tr></tbody> </table> <input type="button" class="btn btn-success addRow" onclick="add_row(' + index + '); " value=" + Add More Payroll Item"></form>  </div><hr />');

        $('.EmpTable').append(rows);

      });

    }

  }
});
```

**WHERE I TRIED GETTING THE VALUES OF THE INPUT FIELD BY ID**

```js
$('#saveAdj').click(function() {
  $('form').each(function() {

    alert($('.EmpId').val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#saveAdj').click(function() {
  $('form').each(function() {
    var thisForm = this;
    alert($('.EmpId', thisForm).val());
  });
});
```

`$('selector', container)` will help you to search from container only;

Answer (score 0):

You aren't providing any context for where to find `.EmpId`.

The callback function passed to the **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method will automatically be passed values for accessing the collection being enumerated. If you use those argument values, you can provide that context by passing it **[as the second argument](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)** to the JQuery object.

```
$('#saveAdj').click(function() {
  // JQuery's .each() method will automatically pass 3 arguments
  // to the provided callback function:
  //  a reference to the index position of that element
  //  a reference to the element being enumerated at the moment
  $('form').each(function(index, element) {

    // The element argument can be passed as the second argument to 
    // the JQuery object (after the selector) to provide context for where to search
    alert($('.EmpId', element).val());
  });
});
```